# Is it possible to show extra image and button in Launch Screen in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, launch-screen

All the time if I open app I need to show Launch Screen with appname only, but if there is no internet then i need to show launch screen with extra image and button like [this app launch screenImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTSnA.jpg). How is that possible?

For internet checking I am using `Reachability`

if I write below code in loginscreen then alert coming in loginscreen but how to show like above image in launch screen:

**tried code in LoginScreen:**

```
import UIKit
import SystemConfiguration

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    internetCheck()
    
}


func internetCheck(){
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
                       Constants.printLog(message: "Internet Connection Available!")
                   }else{
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "NO internet", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
                   }
}

public class Reachability {

class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
    
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    
    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }
    
    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }
    
    // Working for Cellular and WIFI
    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    let ret = (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    
    return ret
    
}
}
}
```

Where shall I write code for launch screen?
Is it possible to add extra image and button in launch screen if there is no internet or shall I create separate view control to show like above mentioned image. Please suggest and explain me the concept.

Comment: You cannot add buttons on the LaunchScreen. The advice I give you is to show a new UIViewController when the internet is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick for that kind of design. Obviously you CAN add views in your launchscreen BUT you CAN'T bind some codes to those views (i.e. UIButton, and whatnot).

So let's dive in to the **trick.**

Trick is: you can add a controller, right after the launch screen, meaning that controller is exactly the very first screen of your app. And then the UI design for that controller (let's name it **RootViewController)** will be EXACTLY the same with the design of your launch screen.

That will give the users an impression that they're still on the launch screen. And from that **RootViewController**, do your Reachability thing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The only thing you can about your problem is this answer.

Comment: if i add another viewcontroller then i am getting launch screen and that view controller if there is no internet.. if there is no internet then i need to show only that designed view controller.... how

Comment: i have created seperate viewcontroller .. if i create right after launch screen then if i give class name then it says `launch screens may not set custom class name` how